# Do I need RAID drivers to convert an ASUS Zenbook from Windows 8 to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, raid

I have an ASUS Zenbook UX301LA-XH72T 13.3" touch ultrabook, and it runs 500GB SSD on RAID 0 configuration. This notebook is running Windows 8, and I need to switch to Windows 7 but maintain RAID 0 configuration.

Will I have problems maintaining RAID 0 once I switch to Windows 7? I would assume that the RAID 0 configuration is BIOS based and Window's won't even know it, and will only see 1 drive regardless, right? Or will I need to do some weird Windows stuff to maintain the RAID 0 configuration? = which doesn't make sense to me why it would.

Comment: If the RAID was initially set up in Windows, then you will need to set it up again in Windows, but if it's a hardware RAID, then windows wouldn't even know.

Comment: ahh thanks. that makes sense.. but how will i know though? This notebook came pre-setup so i have no idea if it's done under windows 8 or via BIOS as default.. Trying to install windows 7 and i'm getting this: http://i.imgur.com/zy4LnJ2.png

Comment: From the image it shows it is a BIOS raid, since the laptop is looking for drivers to install. These will be the raid drivers. What is the make and model of the laptop? (Edit: Got it from your question)

Comment: Umm you lost me there. if it's a BIOS raid, then windows shouldn't need a raid driver right? like it's just gona see it as a regular 500GB hard drive?

Comment: Like all hardware on the PC, Windows needs to have drivers to use it. Usually Windows has the drivers to manage most hardware built in, but this laptop is much newer than Windows 7, and was built for Windows 8. You will need the RAID drivers to be able to detect the SSD's in RAID. This is normal and I've seen it a few times. I'll have a look for the drivers for you soon.

Comment: ohh ok.. i get it thanks man you're super.. i've been looking around as well.. can't seem to find one tsk...